# Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I need a little help. Because preg_replace is deprecated, I have to convert all my preg_replace to preg_replace_callback...

```
function parse_bb_tpl ($part, $args)
{
    // just a replace, with evaluation...
    return preg_replace (
        '/{([^}\s]+)}/e',
        "isset (\$args['\\1']) ? \$args['\\1'] : '';",
        $this->_tpls[$part]
    );
}
```

Comment: preg_replace is not deprecated, this is the `/e` that is deprecated.

Comment: What do I have to do Casimir?

Comment: I think you need to read the php manual about preg_replace_callback, and search about similar questions in SO.

Comment: Alright thanks Casimir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casimir is correct ... it is the `e` modifier that is being depricated.  `preg_replace_callback` is pretty cool, though.  Basically, you just make a function that gets fed the matches and use that for doing the evaluation.

```
$string = 'The bat is batty in the bathroom';

$string = preg_replace_callback('/bat/', 'cool_function', $string);

print $string;

function cool_function($matches) {
    return '<b>'.$matches[0].'</b>';    
}
```

That outputs this:

```
The <b>bat</b> is <b>bat</b>ty in the <b>bat</b>hroom
```